# NextJS and multer, unable to upload and access files

Tags: next.js, multer

I am currently trying to upload an image using the following code in the front-end using NextJS:

```js
const [avatar, setAvatar]: any = useState<File | null>(null);

    async function handleUpload () {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("avatar", avatar);
        const resp = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/uploadavatar", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
            },
            body: formData
        });
        const json = await resp.json();
        console.log(json.data)
    }
```

And then upload it with multer in the api-endpoint using the following code:

```js
import dbConnect from "../../lib/dbConnect";
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse, PageConfig } from 'next'
import authenticated from "../../lib/authenticated";
const multer = require("multer");

export default authenticated(async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
    await dbConnect()
    const {method} = req
    const storage = multer.memoryStorage();
    const upload = multer({storage: storage});

    if (method === "POST") {
        try {
            upload.single("avatar")
            const file = req.file;
            res.status(200).json({success: true, data: file})
        } catch {
            res.status(400).json({success: false})
        }
    };
});

export const config: PageConfig = {
    api: {
        bodyParser: false
    }
}
```

When I try to log the `file` variable, it just returns undefined. I am not sure why it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

The code is provided below to solve this error. But make sure to use nextjs 13 in the pages directory only as multer is not working correctly in the next js 13 app router.

Frontend Code

```
    const handleSubmit = async e => {
    const body = new FormData();
    body.append('pdf', file);
    const response = await axios.post('/api/pdf', body, {});
    console.log(response.data);
    setData(response.data);
};
```

Backend Code

```
import { createRouter } from 'next-connect';
import fs from 'fs';
import pdf from 'pdf-parse';
import multer from 'multer';

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
destination: 'public/uploads/',
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname);
  },
});
const upload = multer({ storage: storage });
const router = createRouter();

router.use(upload.any()).post(async (req, res) => {
let pdfText = '';
console.log('files number', req.files.length);
let dataBuffer = fs.readFileSync(req.files[0].path);

await pdf(dataBuffer).then(function (data) {
    pdfText = data.text.slice(500, 2300);
    console.log(data.text.slice(500, 2300));
});
});

  export default router.handler({
onError: (err, req, res) => {
    console.error(err.stack);
    // res.end(err.message);
    res.end(err);
},
});

export const config = {
api: {
    bodyParser: false,
},
};
```